# MongoDB mongoose how to find collections count where their is a field called duration

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a model called `Session`.

Initially there was no property called `duration`, but later on we added that to our model.

I want to get the documents where there is a property called `duration`.

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. I only want the documents where there is a property called `duration`.

```
await db.Session.find({}).select({ "duration": 1, "_id": 0})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
db.Session.find({},{"duration":1,"_id":0});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can search for exists operator. use this link [Mongodb Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)
one of the example can be written as follows if you have a model called users

```
db.users.find({
  duration: {
    $exists: true
  }
})
```

check this [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0fXE5zoE-_o)

Answer (score 0):

Check This:

```
db.Session.find({"duration": {$exists: true}})
```